# How to hide "ownsObjects" and "listHelper" TObjectList's properties from a Json using Delphi (Rest.JSON)?

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo, object-serialization

I'm using Delphi Tokyo and trying to convert an object into a json using TJson. ObjectToJsonString method present in Rest.Json.
A simple object with simple properties such as String or Integer it's ok, but when a add a property TObjectList, the json is poluted with the properties "ownsObjects" and "listHelper", but the WebService doesn't accept these  fields. How can I "hide" it from a Json?

Comment: Have u tried adding "[JSONMarshalled(False)]" as an attribute to your property?

Comment: I'm able to use "[JSONMarshalled(False)]" to "hide" the properties of my class, but I can't use it to "hide" the properties from TObjectList class, right?

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to still keep the TObjectList property, but without the "ownsObjects" and other internal values. Not with the `Rest.TJson` class at least. You can do it with other implementation that offer more control like [superobject](https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject) or [Synopse](https://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#TITL_52). They might require some manual configuration of the serialization though.

Comment: You can write your own converter.

Comment: @FernandoVallim Have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can put the `JsonReflect` attribute on fields and control how they are being serialized.

Here is some example code of how to write your own specialized "serialize this object list as array" attribute that takes care of that - just add the unit to the uses and add `[SerializeObjectList]` to your field.

```
unit CollectionsReflect;

interface

uses
  Generics.Collections,
  REST.JsonReflect;

type
  SerializeObjectListAttribute = class(JsonReflectAttribute)
    constructor Create;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Rtti;

type
  TListOfObjectInterceptor = class(TJSONInterceptor)
    function ObjectsConverter(Data: TObject; Field: string): TListOfObjects; override;
  end;

{ TListOfObjectInterceptor }

function TListOfObjectInterceptor.ObjectsConverter(Data: TObject;
  Field: string): TListOfObjects;
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  list: TList<TObject>;
begin
  list := TList<TObject>(ctx.GetType(Data.ClassInfo).GetField(Field).GetValue(Data).AsObject);
  Result := TListOfObjects(list.List);
  SetLength(Result, list.Count);
end;

{ SerializeObjectListAttribute }

constructor SerializeObjectListAttribute.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(ctObjects, rtObjects, TListOfObjectInterceptor);
end;

end.
```

Unfortunately the opposite way does not work this way as there seems to be a bug inside of `TJSONUnMarshal.PopulateFields` that causes an AV when trying to populate the list from the json string.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // How to hide “ownsObjects” and “listHelper” TObjectList's properties from a Json
type
  TSameClass = class(...)
    ....
  public
    ...
    function GetAsJson: string;
    ...
  end;

   ...

// метод любого класса Txxxxx для получения его json, у которого, для всех его
// переменных с типом TObjectList, будут очищены “ownsObjects” и “listHelper” свойства
function TSameClass.GetAsJson: string;

  procedure ClearJsonObjectList(AJson: TJSONObject);
  var je: TJSONObject.TEnumerator;
  begin
    // проходим по всему дереву json и удаляем ненужные нам пары
    je := AJson.GetEnumerator();
    while je.MoveNext() do
      if je.Current.JsonValue is TJSONObject then
        // рекурсивный вызов
        ClearJsonObjectList(je.Current.JsonValue as TJSONObject)
      else
      // если есть этот Pair, то есть и другой
      if Assigned(AJson.RemovePair('listHelper')) then
        AJson.RemovePair('ownsObjects');
  end;

var j: TJSONObject;
begin
  // получаем json класса, в котором могут быть или не быть TObjectList с ненужными нам парами
  j := TJson.ObjectToJsonObject(Self);
  // в этой процедуре очищаем полученный json от этих пар
  ClearJsonObjectList(j);
  // возвращаем результат в виде строки json
  Result := j.ToString;
end;
(*
// example
// json before ClearJsonObjectList --------------->
  {
    "content":{
      "checkClose":{
        "payments":{
          "ownsObjects":true,    <<-- must be removed
          "listHelper":[         <<-- must be removed
          ]
        },
        ...
      },
      "positions":{
        "ownsObjects":true,   <<-- must be removed
        "listHelper":[        <<-- must be removed
        ]
      },
      ...
    },
    ...
  }

// json after ClearJsonObjectList --------------->

  {
    "content":{
      "checkClose":{
        "payments":{
        },
        ...
      },
      "positions":{
      },
      ...
    },
    ...
  }
*)
```

Comment: hi ! you need to add code explanation, intent of the variables/functions/constructs, since it will help future readers to understand quicker and better.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you **create an array of objects** instead of a list, if not generally, then for the purpose of serialization to JSON. This works much better with JSON, both reading and writing.  Just make sure to handle the memory involved, i.e. free the objects in the list, something like this:

```
procedure TSomeContainerObject.BeforeDestruction;
var
  o: TSomeObjectInTheArray;
begin
  for o in fObjectArray do
    o.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

I usually put this in my *.dpr file just to make sure:

```
begin
  {$IFDEF Debug}
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := true;
  {$ENDIF}  
  // The rest of your startup code here
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

an improvement on nikhil swami's solution is:

```
procedure ClearJsonObjectList(AJson: TJSONObject);
  function GetAsObjectList(AJson: TJSONObject): TJSONPair;
  var
    ownsObjects, listHelper: TJSONPair;
  begin
    Result := nil;
    if AJson.Count = 2 then
    begin
      ownsObjects := AJson.Get('ownsObjects');
      listHelper := AJson.Get('listHelper');
      if Assigned(ownsObjects) and Assigned(listHelper) then
        if (ownsObjects.JsonValue is TJSONBool) and (listHelper.JsonValue is TJSONArray) then
        begin
          AJson.RemovePair(ownsObjects.JsonString.Value);
          AJson.RemovePair(listHelper.JsonString.Value);
          Result := listHelper;
        end;
    end;
  end;
var
  index: integer;
  itemName: string;
  itemValue: TJSONObject;
  list: TJSONPair;
begin
  for index := Pred(AJson.Count) downto 0 do
    if AJson.Pairs[index].JsonValue is TJSONObject then
    begin
      itemValue := TJSONObject(AJson.Pairs[index].JsonValue);
      list := GetAsObjectList(itemValue);
      if Assigned(list) then
      begin
        itemName := AJson.Pairs[index].JsonString.Value;
        AJson.RemovePair(itemName);
        AJson.AddPair(itemName, list.JsonValue);
      end
      else
        ClearJsonObjectList(itemValue);
    end;
end;
```

- the ClearJsonObjectList function will replace the ObjectList as an object with a list/array, keeping the values.

Answer (score -1):

```
uses
  System.Json;

Function GetNode(AJson, ANode: String): String;    
var
  JsonArray: TJSONArray;
  JsonValue: TJSONValue;

begin     
 JSonValue := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(AJson);

  if Assigned(JSonValue) and (JSonValue is TJSONObject) then
      JsonArray := TJSONObject(JSonValue).GetValue(ANode) as TJSONArray;

  Result := JsonArray.ToString
end;
```

**Example of use:**

```
StringJson := GetNode(DirtyJsonString, 'listHelper');
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -2):

```
function TSrvMethContab.GetConecctions: TJSONObject;
var
 lContext : TDbContext ;
 lLista : TList<TConexions>;
 jResult : TJSONObject;
begin
  lContext := TDbContext.Create(strConexion);
  try
   lLista := lContext.Select<TConexions>();
   jResult := TJson.ObjectToJsonObject(lLista);
   jResult.RemovePair('listHelper');
   Result := jResult;
  finally
   lContext.Free;
 end;
end;
```

Comment: When answering on SO you should try to explain what you did/changed, to better help the OP & any future visitors who may see your answer.