# Custom converter for TJsonMarshal in Delphi 11

Tags: json, delphi, marshalling

I am trying to register a custom converter to avoid the inherited properties in `TObjectList` - mainly `FListHelper` and `FOwnsObjects`. But I cannot get the custom converter to register, and the documentation shows no real examples.

(No this is not a duplicate of: [How to hide "ownsObjects" and "listHelper" TObjectList's properties from a Json using Delphi (Rest.JSON)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48566890/))

I am trying to get a converter Registered - but it seems to never run.

I have wrapped it in a custom class of mine that looks like this:

```
TMyJsonConverter = class(TJsonConverter)
  class function JsonConvert(ObjectToConvert:TObject): string;
  private
    type
      TListOfObjectInterceptor = class(TJSONInterceptor)
        function ObjectsConverter(Data: TObject; Field:string): TListOfObjects; override;
    end;
  end;


function TMyJsonConverter.TListOfObjectInterceptor.ObjectsConverter(Data: TObject; Field:string): TListOfObjects;
begin
  raise Exception.Create('converter found');
end;

class function TMyJsonConverter.JsonConvert(ObjectToConvert: TObject): string; 
begin
  var customConverter := TMyJsonConverter.TListOfObjectInterceptor.Create();
  var otherConverter := TMyJsonConverter.Create;
  var marshaller := TJSONMarshal.Create(otherconverter);

  marshaller.RegisterConverter(
    ObjectToConvert.ClassType,
    '*',
    customConverter.ObjectsConverter
  );

  var json := marshaller.Marshal(ObjectToConvert);

  try
    exit(json.ToString);
  finally
    marshaller.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I have tried to register the types of `TObjectConverter`, `TObjectsConverter`, `TTypeObjectsConverter` but I never seem to get into the conversion function. I can see that the call to register does register the converter, but when I marshal the JSON, it does not find the custom converter again.

Here is a sample structure that highlights the issue, I want to marshal `TMySampleDTO` as JSON:

```
type
  TEmployee = class
  public
    Id: Integer;
    Name: string;
  end;
  TEmployeeList = class(TObjectList<TEmployee>);

  TWorktime = class
  public
    EmployeeId: Integer;
    DepartmentId: Integer;
    StartTime: TDateTime;
    StopTime: TDateTime;
  end;
  TWorktimeList = class(TObjectList<TWorktime>);

  TDepartment = class
  public
    Id: Integer;
    Address: string;
    Employees: TEmployeelist;
  end;
  TDepartmentList = class(TObjectList<TDepartment>);

  TMySampleDTO = class
  public
    Departments: TDepartmentList;
    Worktimes: TWorktimeList;
    Employees: TEmployeeList;
  end;
```

---

**UPDATE:** I got the Converter to run, apparently even though Embarcadero defined the const `FIELD_ANY` as `'*'`, it doesn't run if you don't specify the exact fieldname, in my case `FListHelper`. This raises the next issue though, I also have to give the exact type, as it doesn't check for inheritance. So if my object structure has properties derived from `TObjectList<T>` all those lists will be serialized as objects with a list as a property.

Comment: Could you provide sample data structure that you're trying to serialize to JSON?

Comment: @PeterWolf I have added some data that might show my issue :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide "ownsObjects" and "listHelper" TObjectList's properties from a Json using Delphi (Rest.JSON)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48566890/how-to-hide-ownsobjects-and-listhelper-tobjectlists-properties-from-a-json)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I did read that answer thoroughly and it was what got me on the track of the custom converter. My issue is that I want this to be my generic converter for all my entities. And I must say  that I think that it is ugly having to annotate all my models with JsonReflect attributes. So essentially I want to do what Stefan did in his answer, but without the attribute.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the cleanup - however I didn't really answer the question, as mentioned it is now called but still does not work properly.

Comment: @MattBaech See `ListTypeConverter` function and how to register it in my answer.  For instance, single registration of type converter for `TEmployeeList` will apply to field `Employees` of class `TMySampleDTO` as well as field `Employees` of class `TDepartment`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that works - for some reason it doesnt work when the top level object is a list, but I can live with that for now. It uses RTTI and some questionable methods for finding Lists in an object, but it works for me - somewhat.

If `ObjectToConvert` is a `TList<T>` descendant, it will still return json as an object with the property listHelper, containing the elements of the list.

*But only for the top level object*

If anyone can figure out why the converter doesn't work for the top list (outermost json value), feel free to tell me why, and I will add it to solution.

```
procedure FindObjectListsInHierarchy(obj: TObject; var result: TList<TClass>);

  function IsListDescendant(clazz:TClass) : boolean;
  begin
    result := false;
    while clazz <> nil do
    begin
      if clazz.ClassName.StartsWith('TList<') then
         exit(true);
      clazz := clazz.ClassParent;
    end;
  end;

begin
  if not assigned(result) then
    Result := TList<TClass>.Create;

  var ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  var objType := ctx.GetType(obj.ClassType);

  for var prop in objType.GetProperties do
  begin
    if not ((prop.Visibility = mvPublic) or (prop.Visibility = mvPublished)) then
      continue;

    if prop.PropertyType.TypeKind in [tkClass, tkDynarray] then
    begin
      if IsListDescendant(TRttiInstanceType(Prop.Parent).MetaclassType) then
      begin
        if not result.Contains(obj.ClassType) then
          Result.Add(obj.ClassType);

        for var item in TList(Obj) do
          FindObjectListsInHierarchy(item, result);
      end;

      if prop.PropertyType.TypeKind = tkClass then
        FindObjectListsInHierarchy(prop.GetValue(obj).AsObject, result);
    end;
  end;
end;

function TMyJsonConverter.TypeObjectsConverter(Data: TObject): TListOfObjects;
begin
  var list := TList<TObject>(Data);
  Result := TListOfObjects(list.List);
  SetLength(Result, list.Count);
end;

function TMyJsonConverter.JsonConvert(ObjectToConvert: TObject): string;
begin
  var marshaller := TJSONMarshal.Create;
  try
    var listObjects: TList<TClass> := nil;
    try
      FindObjectListsInHierarchy(ObjectToConvert, listObjects);
      for var o in listObjects do
      begin
        marshaller.RegisterJSONMarshalled(o, 'FOwnsObjects', false);
        marshaller.RegisterConverter(o, TypeObjectsConverter);
      end;
    finally
      listObjects.Free;
    end;

    var json := marshaller.Marshal(ObjectToConvert);
    result := json.ToString;
    json.Free;
  finally
    marshaller.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The question was why your converter registration didn't work. In my answer I explained in detail where did you go wrong and how to do it correctly. I also advised you to drop usage of `JsonInterceptor` in combination with `RegisterConverter` which you seem to ignore.

Comment: You have updated original post with new question which in my opinion should go to a separate post. Anyway, answer to that question is that Delphi JSON library is flawed and it will only work if you register interceptor using `JsonReflect` attribute with `ctTypeObjects` converter in your case, e.g.:`[JsonReflect(ctTypeObjects, rtTypeObjects, TMyJsonInterceptor)] TEmployeeList = class(TObjectList<TEmployee>);`. With that said, if you really need to use Delphi JSON library, I'd recommend you to mark all your custom list types with `JsonReflect` attribute and that's all you have to do.

Comment: @PeterWolf My original question was how I got a converter to work with specifically descendants of `TObjectList<T>`, that I had an error in my converter registration was simply part of the solution. The JsonInterceptor was again an error on my side, since I saw that the `TJsonInterceptor` had virtual methods that matches the convertertion routines needed, I have now omitted that and will update my answer accordingly.

I will not use attributes on hundreds or thousands of classes in a multi million line code base as I see no benefit of these classes to hold serialization specific knowledge.

Comment: @PeterWolf I DO recognize that the attributes are the intended way for this to work, but it does not solve my use case. Therefore this question.

Comment: That's the point - it's not possible with `TJSONMarshal`. You can check it yourself in `TTypeMarshaller<TSerial>.MarshalData` method (System.JsonReflect.pas). After checking for `nil` value it calls `GetTypeConverter` method to resolve type interceptor declared by `JsonReflect` attribute. If there's none, it ignores any registered converters and proceeeds directly with marshalling the type's fields.

Comment: @PeterWolf But the solution I posted works - I am off hours now so I won't bother looking at the code at the moment. But for whatever reason the code i posted works and converts the lists into arrays which can be marshalled

Comment: That comment was related to registering converter for top-level objects.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/API:REST.JsonReflect.TTypeMarshaller.RegisterConverter) for `TTypeMarshaller.RegisterConverter` lacks any detailed information leaving you no option but to study Delphi RTL source code. At first look we can divide all overloaded versions of the method into 3 groups:

1. An overload with 3 parameters with last parameter of type `TConverterEvent` - registers a converter, which performs conversion based on its [`ConverterType`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.JsonReflect.TConverterEvent.ConverterType) property. This property read-only, but its value is set along with setting any of its [conversion delegates](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.JsonReflect.TConverterEvent_Properties) (`*Converter` properties).
2. Overloads with 3 parameters with last parameter of type `T...Converter` - registers a converter for `FieldName` (2nd parameter) within class type `clazz` (1st parameter). Let's call it a *"field converter"*.
3. Overloads with 2 parameters with last parameter of type `TType...Converter` - registers a converter for class type `clazz` (1st parameter). This basically calls the first overload with `FieldName` set to `'*'`, which is reserved for type converters.

In your sample code you are registering a field converter for field with name `*` within class type of an instance provided as an argument to your `TMyJsonConverter.JsonConvert` method. That explains why your conversion routine is not invoked.

Furthermore you create an instance `TListOfObjectInterceptor` in order to pass a reference to its `ObjectsConverter` method to `TTypeMarshaller.RegisterConverter` method. This way you leak this `TListOfObjectInterceptor` instance. Interceptors should be used in combination with [`JsonReflect`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.JsonReflect.JsonReflectAttribute) attribute.

The correct way to register a field converter is:

```
function ListFieldConverter(Data: TObject; Field: string): TListOfObjects;
var
  RttiContext: TRttiContext;
  List: TList<TObject>;
begin
  List := TList<TObject>(RttiContext.GetType(Data.ClassInfo).GetField(Field).GetValue(Data).AsObject);
  Result := TListOfObjects(List.List);
  SetLength(Result, List.Count); // makes unique copy
end;

{ ... }

marshaller.RegisterConverter(TMySampleDTO, 'Employees', ListFieldConverter);
marshaller.RegisterConverter(TMySampleDTO, 'Departments', ListFieldConverter);
marshaller.RegisterConverter(TDepartment, 'Employees', ListFieldConverter);
marshaller.RegisterConverter(TMySampleDTO, 'Worktimes', ListFieldConverter);
```

The correct way to register a type converter is:

```
function ListTypeConverter(Data: TObject): TListOfObjects;
var
  List: TList<TObject>;
begin
  List := TList<TObject>(Data);
  Result := TListOfObjects(List.List);
  SetLength(Result, List.Count); // makes unique copy
end;

{ ... }

marshaller.RegisterConverter(TEmployeeList, ListTypeConverter);
marshaller.RegisterConverter(TDepartmentList, ListTypeConverter);
marshaller.RegisterConverter(TWorktimeList, ListTypeConverter);
```

As you can see, this is as much work as using `JsonReflect` attributes. In theory you could register converters dynamically based on RTTI, but this can be cumbersome due to nested types and inheritance.

To sum that up, even though Delphi JSON library provides ways to hook into the marshalling process, it's not very flexible and supports only very basic scenarios (see also recent question [Spring4D Nullable JSON serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77114037/11562188)).

The last thing I'd like to point out is that you should pay more attention to conventions. Fields of records/classes should be prefixed with `F` by convention. Delphi JSON library honors that and removes those `F`'s in process of serialization. Serializing `type TData = class Foo: string; end;` to JSON yields: `{"oo":""}`.

Comment: I did somehow manage to get it to work using much the same method, but dynamic so I don't have to have hard coupling between my json converter and all entities in my entire codebase.

As for your last point, that was a copy paste mistake and I have updated the example in my question.

I will create a self answer with my new converter, but it still doesnt quite work, but it gets me 95% there, it still refuses to call the converter on the top level List object, but everything else is converted as i expect.